# Why does my Bird of Paradise have arrested development?

Tags: houseplants, growth

I've had a Bird of Paradise for about two years and it has done well in its current location, which is an office building with three huge, west-facing windows so it gets bright indirect light most of the day and a few hours of direct light in late afternoon. I water it every other week and fertilize it twice a year with a slow-acting fertilizer according to label directions.

It put out a new leaf in year one (top right leaf) and then around the beginning of 2023 it put out the new sprout you see in the center. That sprout was developing normally for the first few weeks and then it just stopped. It's still bright green, still looks healthy, but it hasn't grown in months, not even a little.

I'm baffled what could be the problem. A friend who's more knowledgeable about plants than I was also baffled. Any ideas what the problem could be?

[image]

Comment: How long is a tropical plant going to grow indoors without 6-8 hours of full blazing sun? Not crazy about the way the soil looks. I'm feeling fresh soil, more water, and more sun.

Comment: The darkness of the current substrate and your sensible watering regime suggests that, typical of office plants, some additional people have also taken it upon themselves to also water this plant perhaps? 

This calls for a tarpauline and tipping out the current plant and substrate and undertaking a thorough examination of roots, substrate and outer pot for water. My suspicion is the lower saturated areas of the substrate in the Perched Water Table are holding onto too much water and root rot has occurred but only examining with yuor fingers, eyes and nose will answer that issue.